# How to block other url for forcing user to reset password spring security 4

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using spring security 4 for login and reset password functionality.I'm able to do login successfully but after that i have to redirect user to password reset page if his password get expired.For that i'm calling  one handler after successfully authenticated but the issue with it that is all urls are now open and user can go to other urls without changing password.

here my all config files

security config file

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
                 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:property="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

        <!-- Spring MVC based authentication, login page etc.  -->
        <http pattern="/rs/login" security="none"/>
        <http>
            <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
            <form-login login-page="/rs/login" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
                        authentication-failure-url="/login"
                        authentication-success-handler-ref="ResetHandler"/>
            <logout logout-success-url="/login"/>
            <csrf disabled="true"/>
        </http>

        <!-- Declared authentication manager -->
        <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <authentication-provider ref="AuthenticationManager" />
        </authentication-manager>

        <!-- Bean implementing AuthenticationProvider of Spring Security -->
        <beans:bean id="AuthenticationManager" class="authentication.rest.AuthenticationManager">
        </beans:bean>

    </beans:beans>
```

Here my success handler

```
    @Component
    public class ResetHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler
    {
        private AuthenticationSuccessHandler target = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();

        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth) {


            if (checkCredentialExpired(auth.getPrincipal())) {
                try
                {
                    response.sendRedirect("/RESTfulExample/rs/resetPassword");
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (
            else{
                try
                {
                    target.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, auth);
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ServletException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void proceed(HttpServletRequest request,
                            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth) {
            try
            {
                target.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, auth);
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ServletException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

At this page i'm redirecting to reset page successfully but if some one use other urls those are now open as we have call this handler after success,

I also tried to call it in failure handler like credentials are expired check if true then return failure but then i'm not able to check either they fail due to credentials failure or due to password expired check.

please help me with this